# How to search an HTML table that collects data from Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

trying to do a search on an html table want to be able to type the users nickname and it gives me all the users details on the same table.

```
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nickname</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                    <th>city</th>
                                    <th>address</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM houses"; 
            $q=$conn->query($sql);
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
 ?>
              <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
           }

        ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: with a where clause

Answer (score -1):

You need to use WHERE in your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE nickname = '{$nickname}'";
```

> you also need to use an isset in order to have the word from your HTML input.

Comment: am presently using javascript to  do the search, the code i uploaded above is for populating the table, due to this line of code ""

Comment: couldn't edit the previous comment.  
am presently using javascript to do the search, the code i uploaded above is for populating the table, due to this line of code 'td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];' i want to be able to search through all the columns, how do i append the numbers to this line