# Populate HTML Table with database values

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table that contains city, person, employment_status. I want to populate my html table with this values using PHP, the first `td` will contain a city the next will contain the total number of people in that city and the third `td` will contain the total number of people employed. Normally I populate my table using while but this one I don't know how to go about the mysqli query and if while will also work, checked for a solution but can't find, been stuck here for days.

```
                                      <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover search-table" >
                         <tbody>
                       <thead>
                          <tr>
                             <th><i class="icon_profile"></i> city</th>
                             <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> Total number of people</th>
                             <th><i class="icon_pin_alt"></i> no of pepople employed</th>

                          </tr>
                          </thead>

                           <?php
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT city) FROM user"; 
            $q=$conn->query($sql);
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
```

am stuck here, the query part of it, there is no row created in db to provide me this values

Comment: It doesn't work like that my man, you have to show us the code so we can see what you have done so far... show us the code then we will take it from there.

Comment: there are many tutorials available for that . here  is one http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d9da8a/display-data-with-html-table-in-php/

Comment: Just the same way as you did before, in another question you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031821/how-to-search-an-html-table-that-collects-data-from-mysqli

Comment: the tutorial is not available@mahethekiller

Comment: the problem i have is how to manipulate the msqli query to give me the desired result i stated above

Comment: So then you're looking for what kind of query to use? That didn't really come across in your question *at all*. Sample query: `SELECT city, COUNT(person) as person_count FROM table WHERE ....` (obviously need more work) - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 1):

As the people suggested in the comments. You'll have to show what have you done so far.But this code may come helpful.I am using using mysqli connection.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>City</td>
    <th>Person</td>
    <th>Employment Status</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$SELECT = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
if($SELECT != false)
{
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($SELECT))
    {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$rows["city"]."</td>
            <td>".$rows["person"]."</td>
            <td>".$rows["employment_status"]."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "
        <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>Something went wrong with the query</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `"normally i populate my table using while"` means he knows that silly basic syntax.

Comment: thank you, i know the basic syntax, that's why i didn't put it there, the problem i have is how to manipulate the msqli query to give me the desired result i stated above