# Create PHP Table/Graph with Mysql Data from selected user

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a little website where I can check, via table and graph, different kinds of data sent to a mysql database from users.

On the top of the page I have a select box with the names from all the users (when I pick one I get the user Id) and I can get the mysql data associated with said user with an Ajax get function that retrived the data in JSON (I've used this method to fill forms and it works fine).

My question/doubt is how can I take that JSON data from the Ajax get function and fill the table + use it to draw the graph with the Google API.

I'll put a snipet of the html page just for context:

```
<html>
    <body id = "analyseTemperatureBody">
        <div class = "background">
            <h1>Informação Geral</h1>
            <div class = "formSquare">
                <select name="patient" id ="patient" onChange = "getTemperature(this.value)" required>
                    <option value=""></option>  
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM patients ORDER BY patientName";
                        $patients = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                        foreach($patients as $patient) {  
                            echo ("<option value=".$patient["patientId"].">".$patient["patientName"]."</option>");  
                        }  
                    ?>
                </select>
                <table id = "tempTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date-Time</th>
                        <th>Value (ºC)</th>
                    </tr>
                    -> want to fill the various rows here
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function getTemperature(val){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../ajax/ajax_populate_temperature.php",
        data: 'patient='+val,
        success: function(response){
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            if (result.response == true) {
                var data = result.rows;

            }
            else if (result.response == false) {

            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

For the graph part I've been looking into using Google's API but like I said, I need to find a way to make the data "reach" the functions to draw.

I'm open for suggestions/references/guidance since I've been trying to search info for some hours now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for StackOverflow - I mean asking for general techniques. However, look here to see how to populate a table from PHP <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418141/populate-html-table-with-database-values>. Also here is a good tutorial for Google Graphs. <https://www.tutorialspoint.com/googlecharts/googlecharts_configuration_syntax.htm>

Comment: When you have made some attempts, and you still have problems StackOverflow is a great site to help you find the problem, and you can ask questions like "Here is the code I have tried so far, what am I doing wrong".